# wait for images in div to load before fadeIn() with ajax appended content and jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, fadein

I'm working on a site that loads pages of images into a div using jquery's $.ajax. When the user scrolls to the bottom of the page, another page of images is loaded into the div. Currently I have the new content fading in, but it is fading in before the images are fully loaded. I checked for a solution but couldn't find any that worked for me. To clarify, each set of images is a div filled with divs for the individual images.

Here is the load function I am using:

```
function loadContent(pageName, pageView, max_feed){
        loader="<div id=loader><img src=SPACER" height=\"100\" \>"
            + "<br/><img src=\"LOADER" />"
            + "<br/><img src=\"SPACER" height=\"100\" \></div>";
        $(loader).appendTo('#photo_container').fadeIn('fast');
        $.ajax({
            url:pageName,
            data:{view:pageView, max_feed_id:max_feed},
            success:function(result){
                $('#loader').remove();                  
                $(result)
                    .appendTo('#photo_container')
                    .hide()
                    .fadeIn('slow');
                $(window).data('loading', false);
            }
        });
    };
```

Is there any simple way that I could wait for the new content to load before fadeIn() is called? i.e. is there something similar to

```
$(window).load(...)
```

that I could use for just the div content? I was thinking of setting some sort of global variable like isLoadingMore then setting that to false in the beginning of the ajax loaded content, and then adding in the

```
$(window).load(...)
```

function to the ajax page that would have a function in it to set the variable to true and then just adding a while loop or something that would wait for that flag to be set to true before calling the fadeIn function in the loadContent function. Don't know if that would be a good idea though or even work

Answer (score 4):

On your images you can have do the following

```
$('img').load(function(e){
$(this).fadeIn();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a good candidate for my plugin: [waitForImages](https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages).